# How do I res.sendFile back one level

Tags: node.js, express, path

This is the error message I keep getting but I am not sure how to go back on level in order to reach client.

```
Error: ENOENT:no such file or directory, stat '/home/template-react-redux/server/client/public/index.html'
```

```
app.get('/i', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public', 'index.html'));
});
```

This is my directory structure

```
/template-react-redux/
....server/
........index.js
....client/
........public/
............index.html
```

Comment: can u try '../client/public'

Comment: I thought I tried this solution earlier, but it worked this time!

Comment: Thank you so much!